# Full screen jQuery Cycle, resize window

Tags: jquery, cycle, jquery-cycle

I'm trying to build a slideshow with jQuery Cycle where the images fills the entire browser, are adjusted so they're always centered and scrolls horizontally (scrollHorz) on click.

It all works pretty good, but when I adjust browser window size, the scroll distance is not adjusted according to the scaling of the image.

Can such adjustment be accomplished? Here's my source code: http://jsfiddle.net/taifun/GWrbB/

I know I can fix scaling of current image by using the $(window).resize event but that's not the problem.

Any suggestions will be appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at Maximage 2.0… it uses jQuery Cycle plugin to create fullscreen background slideshows.  Looks like it does what you are looking for.

http://www.aaronvanderzwan.com/blog/2011/11/maximage-2-0-beta1-release/

Answer (score 0):

You need to adjust the scroll distance (left or margin-left) based on the screen width after resize. I am not sure what attribute cycle uses to do this.  Much like you are resize the image after resize you'll also need to set the start position.